# Limits of Running Foundation, Server 2012, SQL 2012 Express

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql, windows-server

What are some of the major limitations of using SharePoint Foundation 2013, it's compatibility with Server 2012 Standard, and the limitations of SQL 2012 Express?

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of capacity and performance there are no limitations.
>   SharePoint makes use of certain features in SQL Server Enterprise to
>   enhance performance, such as table partitioning.

For SQL Server Express, database limitation is 10GB only.
Some features which are not present in foundation:

Custom site definitions Site provisioning.

InfoPath forms service

Access Services

Workflow Management-based workflows

Documents Sets

Managed Metadata

Document IDs

REFERENCES:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise

http://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c2c3bdbc-2e48-436c-9bb8-b604f00de8fa/sharepoint-foundation-2013-limitation